# Centering navigation borders on wordpress twentytwelve

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to center the top and bottom borders on the site I am working on http://www.listentotheway.com . The right side is extended out more than I would like. Also, I added this code to avoid stacking:

> ```
> .menu-main-menu-container {
>   width: 1100px;
>   }
> ```

Any pointers and help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1100px it is too wide for your 960 css, try to use this:

```
    .menu-main-menu-container {
        width: 960px;
        margin: auto;
     }
```

Comment: Alex, thank you so much. I was trying to figure it out for an hour in a half and had to ask. Take care.